# Javascript 2nd condition not working, calculate average then change to letter grade

Tags: javascript, average

I've been struggling to find the bug in this code for a couple of days.  Yes, I'm a newbie.  I'm trying to calculate average, then turn numerical output into letter grade.  Please help!  My output reflects that average is calculating but only one condition is working to generate letter grade.

```
var courtesyVal = 0,
overallVal = 0,
i;

if (data.length) {

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    courtesyVal += data[i].grade_courtesy;
    overallVal += data[i].grade_overall;

}

courtesyVal = (courtesyVal / data.length);
overallVal = (overallVal / data.length);

}


if (courtesyVal >= 4 || overallVal >= 4) {
courtesyVal = ("A") || overallVal("A");
} else if (courtesyVal >= 3 || overallVal >= 3) {
courtesyVal = ("B") || overallVal("B");
} else if (courtesyVal >= 2 || overallVal >= 2) {
courtesyVal = ("C") || overallVal("C");
} else if (courtesyVal >= 1 || overallVal >= 1) {
courtesyVal = ("D") || overallVal("D");
} else {
courtesyVal = ("F") || overallVal("F");
}

Appery("courtesy_grade").text(courtesyVal);
Appery("overall_grade").text(overallVal);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems with the code: one severe and one more subtle.

The severe problem is that your syntax treats `overallVal` as a function. `overallVal("A")` attempts to call the `overallVal` function with the first parameter `'A'`. This will result in a an error.

The subtle problem masks the severe one above, because you have assigned to the `courtesyVal` the value of `'A' || overallVal('A')`. Lucky or unlucky for you, the last part is not evaluated, so the error mentioned above is never reached and `'A'` is assigned to `courtesyVal`.

**Solution**

Replace:

```
courtesyVal = ("A") || overallVal("A");
```

With:

```
courtesyVal = "A";
overallVal = "A";
```

One question comes to mind, why are you assigning the same value to both variables? If you want to transform the number grade to a letter grade, then you are doing it incorrectly. You should execute the sequence of if () elses once for each variable.

A better way would be to use some math functions for it:

```
var correspondence = "FDCBAA"; // last A is for a perfect 5
var courtesyVal = 0, overallVal = 0;    

if (data.length) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    courtesyVal += data[i].grade_courtesy;
    overallVal += data[i].grade_overall;
  }

  courtesyVal = (courtesyVal / data.length);
  overallVal = (overallVal / data.length);
}

courtesyVal = correspondence[Math.floor(courtesyVal)];
overallVal = correspondence[Math.floor(overallVal)];
```

Comment: It worked! After struggling for 2 days, it takes me all of 20 minutes to get a fix from you guys.  Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

`||` is short-circuiting, so if the first condition evaluates to `true`, the second is not evaluated. Since you're doing assignments and not conditions, I don't think you want `||` at all. You also probably don't want to call `overallVal` as if it were a function. Try this:

```
courtesyVal = "A";
overallVal = "A";
```

Or even shorter:

```
courtesyVal = overallVal = "A";
```

Answer (score 1):

When you assign the letter grades, you are using OR (||) to separate your assignments.  You need to use 2 separate assignment statements separated by a semi-colon (;).

```
if (courtesyVal >= 4 || overallVal >= 4) {
    courtesyVal = "A";
    overallVal = "A";
} 
else if (courtesyVal >= 3 || overallVal >= 3) {
    courtesyVal = "B";
    overallVal = "B";
} 
else if (courtesyVal >= 2 || overallVal >= 2) {
    courtesyVal = "C";
    overallVal = "C";
} 
else if (courtesyVal >= 1 || overallVal >= 1) {
    courtesyVal = "D"; 
    overallVal = "D";
} 
else {
    courtesyVal = "F"; 
    overallVal = "F";
}
```